# working with session and lazy loading

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Using NHibernate and C#, I am having an issue with deleting an object that is loaded with attribute lazy loading.

The object is.

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual Guid ItemID { get; set; }    
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual string Image { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Tax> Taxes { get; set; }
}
```

The "Taxes" Collection is here loaded with lazy loading. So I need to keep session open(As I learnt). When loading the "Item" object I use the following query.

```
    public Item FindByID(Guid itemID)
    {
        //using(var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        //using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())
        //{
        //    return session.Get<Item>(itemID);
        //}

        var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();
        return session.Get<Item>(itemID);
    }
```

In the above code for `FindByID()` you can see I have commented out some code that is closing the session once the object is fetched from the DB. It was because, I need the session to be open as I have `Taxes` object collection sould be accessed lazy. The open code section show the session is still open after returning the found object.

No when I execute delete using following code with the above loaded object.

```
    public void RemoveItem(Item item)
    {            
        using(var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                session.Delete(item);
                tr.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw Ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error..

> Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

The error is clear, The fetched object has opened session, when I open another session for deleting the same object, this error is produced.

Please someone guide me to get rid of this error. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably specify what your question is, seeing as the error is clear (as you said yourself).

Comment: My question is .. how to solve this error? I wrote it under the question. But I can not see it now. May be deleted by moderator???

Comment: If the `RemoveItem` method above is your actual code, don't do `catch (Exception ex) throw Ex;` you will loose the stack trace - do `catch (Exception ex) throw;` instead. Also, don't catch an exception if all you are going to do is throw it, you should probably be doing a `tr.Rollback()` or something here.

Comment: Thanks for the good point @TrevorPilley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in your design. You are opening a session to get the object, and leaving it open.  You are then opening another session to delete the managed object, but you intend to close this session automatically. So why are you not closing the session in the `FindByID` method?

You need to think about your design as the above is inconsistent - or as Morten says, give a more in-depth question (i.e. how should this be designed).

Since you need access to the lazy instances, you will be better using Morten's approach and using either a session per web request or by setting up your own request context that has a session in it (if you're not creating a web application). An easier approach if you don't already have a context-based design is to create the session at the beginning of your event (i.e user wants to delete an item) and pass the session into the DAO methods:

```
public Item FindByID(Session session, Guid itemID)
{
    using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        return session.Get<Item>(itemID);
    }
}

public void RemoveItem(Session session, Item item)
{
    using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
         session.Delete(item);
         tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

You could take this a step further and create the transaction outside of the DAO too which would be faster and would take full advantage of transactions (i.e later you may have requests that perform database actions that depend on one-another via your generic DAOs).

Comment: yes @TonyDay, in my FindByID method I commented those code because, I was getting the error when I try to access the lazy loaded "Taxes" colllection to output in UI. Once I keep the session opened, that code worked. Ok, I understand from your design, that I should inject the session from outside the method. right?

Comment: Yes, that would be a simple approach. Moving forward you would consider involving a proper context which handles and injects the session for you between requests.  But that just depends on what framework you are using - for example I work with Java (Hibernate and Spring), and Spring injects the session for me and handles transactions on a per-request basis.

Comment: I am on ASP.NET webapp. I have a service layer in between repository and the UI layer which passes the model in and out. Hope I should manage the session from service layer. please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: You are not wrong, but in the long-term it may be better using a request-level approach like this one: http://ayende.com/blog/4101/do-you-need-a-framework or this: http://pwigle.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/nhibernate-session-handling-in-aspnet-the-easy-way/. This way, you create a new session at the start of the ASP.NET request and it closes at the end of the request automatically. All you then need to do is inject a method of accessing this current session into your DAOs.

Comment: Yes @TonyDay, I've implemented this way (http://pwigle.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/nhibernate-session-handling-in-aspnet-the-easy-way/) It works fine for me. Also, I found a better way in Ayende's blog (http://ayende.com/blog/4101/do-you-need-a-framework). I can understand the step of it, but I dont know how to wire up to get this code work with my system.

Comment: I'd stick with the first example if you have that working - it's a good approach and I expect it to be a somewhat simplified version of what any major framework you would use will do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you always have only one session active. There are two popular approaches:

- Have a service layer that you always forward requests to. This service layer is responsible for session handling (and transaction handling). All business logic must be handled in the session layer so you always have a session. You must load everything that you need in the UI and return that as part of your response. See e.g. http://davybrion.github.com/Agatha/ for a simple request response service layer that uses nhibernate.
- Have a session per web request. This usually involves opening a session (and transaction) before a controller method is invoked, and commit the transaction afterwards. Usually this is handled via the use of attributes you put on the methods that needs a session. I cannot give a complete example off the top of my head, but I know that one popular approach is described in [NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using session-per-request pattern in your web application, the easiest solution would be to modify the `NHibernateHelper.OpenSession` method to return the current session for the request. In order to make this work, you cannot wrap session access in a `using` block, instead you would manage the session lifetime in global.asax.

I would take this approach if you have a lot of existing code that you don't want to refactor. If you have the time to refactor then you should use dependency inject to inject the ISession into your repository/query objects.